# What are the reflective properties for 77 GHz electromagnetic waves (automotive RADAR)?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, radar

Automotive radar uses electromagnetic waves around 77 GHz frequency. Is there some data, tables available about the reflectivity of such waves for various materials, like water, stone, people, metal etc. (or ideally reflectivity, absorption and transmission)?

Answer (score 2):

There are some data and tables available about the reflectivity of 77 GHz waves for various materials, but they may not be comprehensive or accurate. Here are some sources that I found:

- [Laboratory Study of Electromagnetic Waves Reflectivity of Certain Materials](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Eugen-Coca/publication/271484234_Laboratory_study_of_electromagnetic_waves_reflectivity_of_certain_materials/links/58890440a6fdcc9a35c144e8/Laboratory-study-of-electromagnetic-waves-reflectivity-of-certain-materials.pdf?origin=publication_detail): This paper presents the results of experimental determinations of the reflectivity of 77 GHz waves for several materials (aluminium, melamine faced fiberboard, and gypsum drywall slabs) in a semi-anechoic chamber. The results show that aluminium is a good reflector, which was expected, but that melamine hardboard reflects 77 GHz waves nearly as well as aluminium. The material used for drywall is less reflective at almost all frequencies. The results also show a fairly significant dependence of reflection properties on frequency, as reflected power decreases with frequency.
- [Reflectivity of some materials at 94 GHz](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01007087): This paper reports the measurements of the relative reflectivity of 94 GHz waves for various materials, such as water, ice, snow, soil, vegetation, and concrete. The data show that nonconducting materials have a relative reflectivity on the order of 2–3%, and that absorbed water can increase the relative reflectivity significantly. The results are expected to be similar for 77 GHz waves, as the wavelength difference is not significant.
- [Wireless signal reflection/absorption on different materials](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342853/wireless-signal-reflection-absorption-on-different-materials): This is a forum discussion where some users share their insights and experiences on how wireless signals are reflected or absorbed by different materials, such as metal, plastic, wood, glass, etc. The discussion is not specific to 77 GHz waves, but it provides some general principles and examples that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[WiGig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiGig) channels are in the range of 57 to 75 GHz, which is close to 77 GHz.  I was able to find some research on WiGig performance. [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224149099_Robust_60_GHz_Indoor_Connectivity_Is_It_Possible_with_Reflections), for example, includes a table that describes the dielectric properties of several materials that radio waves might reflect off of inside a building.

[image: Dielectric Properties of Materials]

The article says that "The attenuation from the reﬂections depends on the material thickness, permittivity and the incident angle [14]." and the reference (14) is to...

> J. Deiner, J. Hbner, D. Hunold, and J. Voigt, “RPS Radiowave Propagation Simulator User manual Version 5.4,” Actix GmbH, 2008.

... which is a tool that you would need to buy if you want to do accurate simulations.

For more reflective objects, such as the chrome bumper of a car, the shape also comes into play.

There are other tools such as Ansys HFSS that you can use if you want to get deep into the weeds.

But if you're just working out a rough link budget, then the article defines the reﬂection loss is as the SNR difference between the direct line-of-sight path and the most dominant reﬂection. They say that in their study, the average reﬂection loss was between 15-20 dB, which includes both the power loss on the reﬂective surface and the extra path loss caused by longer transmission path. This is probably quite small compared to the free space path loss in an automotive radar scenario.

But if you want to produce a more accurate result you should attempt a simulation. A few years a go I obtained a free trial license for Ansys HFSS. That software included a tutorial that walks the user through how to simulate radar waves bouncing off of a helicopter. I think that within the free trial period you could learn enough to simulate a few automotive radar situations.

I recall that the tool is prepopulated with lots of materials. You should be able to find out more about the reflectivity of those materials, at least, directly from the tool.

Hope this is is helpful!